# Why do I need to deliver DevExpress.Printing.v14.2.Core.dll

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-wpf

I have implemented a WPF application using DevExpress controls.
When I was finished, I optimized my references in Visual Studio (using Resharper). I have the following references left:

```
DevExpress.Data.v14.2.dll
DevExpress.Mvvm.v14.2.dll
DevExpress.Xpf.Core.v14.2.dll
DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.v14.2.dll
DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.v14.2.Core.dll
DevExpress.Xpf.Ribbon.v14.2.dll
```

When starting the application on a clean OS, it crashes. With Process Monitor, I find that it is looking in 10 different places for `DevExpress.Printing.v14.2.Core.dll` and cannot find it.

That DLL is 3 MB in size and I'd like to avoid to deliver it, if possible.

Dependency walker seems to not work well for .NET.

I have read [DevExpress about required libraries](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument9370), but that is for XtraReports, which I'm not using in my application.

**Why does my application look for that DLL if it is not referenced?**

Comment: I see you've answered your own question, but in future if you're looking to solve dependency issues, I'd recommend [enabling Fusion logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net), rather than ProcMon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application contains the DXGrid. Thus, according to the [DXGrid's required Redistributable Assemblies list](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6274), the `DevExpress.Printing.v14.2.Core.dll` assembly contains classes that allows to implement the functionality for [DXGrid's printing and exporting](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6160) based on [DXPrinting library](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6570).

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer using JetBrains dotPeek:

DevExpress.Xpf.Core.v14.2.dll and DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.v14.2.dll both have a reference to DevExpress.Printing.v14.2.Core.dll.